# traceback from a warning

Tags: python, warnings, traceback

I have a code which, at some point shows a warning, I think that it is having a problem calculating a `mean()`

I would like to know if there is any way to force python to tell me where, or which line, or whatever more information than just this message:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:55: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:79: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  warnings.warn("Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice", RuntimeWarning)
```

I do not know if it is possible to "catch" a warning.....If I have any error, usually I am using traceback package:

`import traceback`

And then I usually do:

```
try:
    #something
except:
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Traceback of warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373927/get-traceback-of-warnings)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can turn warnings into exceptions:

```
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("error")
```

Now instead of printing a warning, an exception will be raised, giving you a traceback.

You can get the same effect with the [`-W` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W):

```
$ python -W error somescript.py
```

or by setting the [`PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS):

```
$ export PYTHONWARNINGS=error
```

You can play with the other [`warnings.simplefilter()` arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) to be more specific about what warning should raise an exception. You could filter on `warnings.RuntimeWarning` and a line number, for example.

Comment: what are the pros and cons of the first 2 options? The third seems more extreme

Comment: @MikePalmice: all 3 options have the exact same effect, they are just different ways of signalling to the Python binary to change the filter settings.