# How to locate RemovedInDjango19Warning

Tags: django, django-1.9

I'm getting this warning quite frequently:

```
lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
```

I simply have no occurrence of `importlib` in my entire project. I'm assuming it's from a dependency my project have.

My question is:
Where does this warning is coming from? 
How can I determine the source of warning?

As long as I keep my project with the latest Django's version, this might become a problem very soon.

Comment: Both the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373927/get-traceback-of-warnings) might help. Alternatively, you could install the Django 1.9 release candidate in your dev environment, and see what breaks!

Comment: Tx @Alasdair, but actually I'm quite interested to know where the warning is coming from. If it's originated from a deprecated lib, I'd better change the lib asap. You see my point?

Comment: Yes, I understand that you want to know what code is causing the warning. If you install Django 1.9, then the code that uses `django.utils.importlib` will fail, and the traceback will tell you which library is using it. The answer that I linked to has a couple of other options, either by using the `-W` flag to turn warnings into errors, or monkeypatching the code so that the warnings show the traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair gotcha! It make sense. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command grep.

```
grep -r "django.utils.importlib" /path/to/virtual_env
```