# how to fix a ' MaskedArrayFutureWarning ' in python numpy.maximum?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

i am using matplotlib , pandas and numpy to structure my data and plot it , everything is fine and i got the result i need , besides i got the warning :

```
MaskedArrayFutureWarning: In the future the default for ma.maximum.reduce   will be axis=0, not the current None, to match np.maximum.reduce. Explicitly pass 0 or None to silence this warning.
return self.reduce(a)
```

Whats doses this supposed to mean ? How can I get rid of it ?

Comment: Did you use `numpy.ma.maximum` with a single multidimensional argument anywhere in your code?

Comment: No i don't, i am not using numpy.ma.maximum at all in my code !

Comment: Try [replacing `warnings.showwarning` with a function that also prints a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373927/get-traceback-of-warnings), so you can see what part of your code is triggering the warning. Beyond that, we can't help you much.

Comment: It looks like some part of either your code or code you're relying on is calling `numpy.ma.maximum` when it really should be calling `numpy.ma.max`.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] of the issue if you want help in understanding the issue or avoiding it. Otherwise this question is not answerable and should be closed.

Comment: the code i am using is really too long shall I just post it ? Otherwise i think i foun soemthing in this link  [https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/core.py]  but i just don't know what to do with it ?

Comment: No you should of course not post your entire code. You should create a [mcve], which is the minimal code that is needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you used some functions fo pandas or maybe matplotlib. In the source code of matplotlib, for example, 'ma.maximum.reduce' was used when someone used pyplot.contour(). I think maybe you could solve this questions by updating your package.

For instance, I met this warning when I used matplotlib with version 1.5.3. When I updated it to 2.0.2, this warning disappeared.

Whis this could help you.

Comment: yeah that's what i had done too, thank you for replying.