# Python warnings to exceptions in Django tests with ignore

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, exception, warnings

I'm attempting to run Django unit tests using:

`python -We -W ignore:DeprecationWarning -W ignore:UserWarning manage.py test`

However, this doesn't successfully ignore these warning classes, and instead only respects the `-We` flag, raising all warnings to exceptions. This is not my desired behavior.

How can I run Django tests such that all warnings except DeprecationWarning and UserWarning are raised as exceptions when encountered in a test?

Use case: the project I am working on sees a lot of RuntimeWarnings being raised because of naive datetimes in the tests. I want to fix this, but to do so, I have to locate the problematic tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to the filter is message, not module so your exclusions should be:

```
python -We -W ignore::DeprecationWarning -W ignore::UserWarning manage.py test
```

Note the additional colons and see example here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filter

You could also go the other way and only error on `RuntimeWarning`

```
python -W error::RuntimeWarning manage.py test
```

To solve the more general problem you're asking about however it will likely be quicker to print tracebacks with each of your warnings instead. See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22376126/11847125